# Are there any known issues regarding Netty and Ipv6?

Tags: ipv6, netty, testimonials

Testimonial of a successful deployment of Netty application in an Ipv6 only network would be appreciated. Are there any known issues regarding Netty and Ipv6?

Comment: Better suited to Server Fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that we run an application in production that is available over IPv6 and IPv4. This application has both a TCP and UDP protocol.

As suggested, it just works :-)

Answer (score 0):

I never used IPv6 only with Netty but it should just work. There are no limitations in the netty code which I'm aware of.